# adding "or" between proceed to checkout and Paypal button in cart

Tags: checkout, cart, paypal

Since our last upgrade to 1.9 I seem to have lost the "or" between proceed to checkout button and checkout with paypal button in my cart page. Can someone direct me as to where and how to add the proper code for this to show the word "or between these buttons. After our upgrade the paypal was above the proceed to checkout instead of below it. I have managed to get that switched around, just looks odd without or in there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml` file.

Comment: Troy B.,
If this answer worked for you, please mark it with the checkmark.